# Where can I find this Mappr Maps?

Tags: dictionary

[image]

Here's what I find on seeking online, I'm interested in this kind of maps, but don't know where can I find them ? Heres the [Link](http://www.t-hub.co/network) where I found it.

I need this kind of charts to be implemented on my page, tried allot but couldn't find at all, #Emergency please.

It'd be a great pleasure if I got the working example in jsfiddle (or) codepen.

Thanks and Regards

## zeasts

Comment: try with search keyword "mappr"

Comment: You can also try expand http://nifty.works/about/LWbARpVlvYKae3DZ/microsoft-ventures#topic-article for similar knowledge map platforms - disclaimer I am creator of that, I thought you may find useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name stands on the image. `Mappr`. The website is [mappr.io](http://www.mappr.io). But I'm not sure if the product is still available. The company behind Mappr, `Vibrand Data`, has been acquired by `Slice Technologies`. And I don't find any informations about Mappr there. So, good luck wile searching ...

Sources:

- http://mappr.io
- http://vibrantdata.io
- http://slice.com
- [http://blog.slice.com](http://blog.slice.com/2016/06/slice-technologies-acquires-vibrant-data-to-bring-a-new-dimension-to-e-commerce-data/)

Comment: delete this answer please, I cannot ask any more questions, thanks